# Asynchronous messaging in api.ai

Tags: dialogflow-es

I require to send messages asynchronously from my service to api.ai and then api.ai would send it to Facebook Messenger.
To achieve asynchronous messaging I have used custom events.

But on using custom events, events are getting triggered from webhook, and messages are going to api.ai but it is not further displaying anything to facebook messenger

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to add a delay before api.ai replies to user input, right? Than you need to add a delay in your Facebook integration app. 
Consider the follow flow

1. User type a message in Facebook messenger window
2. Facebook sends the message to your integration app
3. Integration app sends the message to api.ai
4. Api.ai responds to the message and send the reply to the integration app
5. Integration app wait for a while and than sends the reply to Facebook

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your approach is good but in my case I require the following integration, 

1)User messages from Facebook Messenger
2)FB Messenger would contact api.ai endpoint
3)api.ai would then send the request to the integrated app
4)After the integrated app is finished with its processing it would send a message to api.ai
5)Now api.ai would forward it to Facebook Messenger

Comment: Is this your requirement or the state of art? I don't think Facebook messenger can call api.ai without integration app.

Comment: Yes you can connect FB Messenger to api.ai, by providing the url of api.ai to FB Messenger.
Then in api.ai, provide the webhook url of your web service.
Kindly check the below link: [link] (https://docs.api.ai/docs/facebook-integration)

Comment: Hey thanks.. have changed the arrangement of the communication model and now it works well.

Comment: I meant I used the approach you suggested me